# I'm getting the illegal character error at $('a[href*=#]').each(function(). what could be the possible reasons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jquery file is also included....
does it having error in quotes used? what can be replaced?

```
<!----- JQUERY FOR SLIDING NAVIGATION --->   
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')
                && location.hostname == this.hostname
                && this.hash.replace(/#/, '')) {
            var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
            if ($target) {
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `#` is a meta-character, pass `#` as a `string` or just try to `escape` it.

Try,

```
$('a[href*="#"]').each(function() {
```

or

```
$('a[href*=\\#]').each(function() {
```

please read [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to know more about meta-characters.

Answer (score 1):

You have special character in name attribute. thus wrap it in quotes:

```
 $('a[href*="#"]').each(function() {
    //rest code
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

If I may suggest a vanilla approach.

`document.links` already returns all the links in the page. `Array.filter` filters an array, but is generic.

You can filter the links by having a hash as such:

```
var filter = Array.prototype.filter;
var withHash = filter.call(document.links,function(a){ return a.hash; });
// withHash now contains all links with a # hash
withHash.forEach(function(el){
    console.log(el," is an anchor element");
});
```

This seems more natural given you're already using .hash in your code. It also does not require jQuery to work and will work with or without it.